# What is the number/structure of units in a function field over $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, function-fields

I know that the units of $\mathbb{F}_q[T] \subset \mathbb{F}_q(T)$ are the constant non-zero polynomials, of which are there $q-1$, and you can think of these as being in analogy with the units $\pm1$ in $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}$.

If $F$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_q(T)$, with integer ring $A$, so the fraction field of $A$ is $F$. Do we know the rank of the unit group of $A$? So we know the size of the unit group $A$? Is something like Dirichlet's unit theorem true in this setting?

Comment: A quick comment: yes, absolutely, an analogue of Dirichlet's Unit's theorem is correct. The salient question is about a correct formulation, about how to replace reference to the archimedean places of a number field (such as $\mathbb Q$) with "primes at infinity", now literally referring to "points at infinity" on the corresponding curve(s). The abstractions in Iwasawa-Tate theory give proofs (a.k.a. Fujisaki's lemma...) that apply to both the number field and function field case, with minor tweaks.

Comment: With $A$ do you mean any (finitely generated) integrally closed subring with fraction field $F$ ?